# Существует для std::stringstream нечто вроде shrink_to_fit?

Tags: c++, stringstream

Скажите, пожалуйста, существует ли для `std::stringstream` аналог `shrink_to_fit`?

Например, я использую поток указанного типа для сериализации и десериализации данных. По мере работы используемая строка потока постоянно расширяется и никогда не сужается. Конечно, можно время от времени делать *уплотнение* руками, но это будет иметь негативные последствия на производительность, учитывая еще и тот факт, что емкость строки *ужатого* потока вновь будет маленькой, и при добавлении данных в такой поток снова будет происходить расширение.

Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1'000'000'000; ++i)
  {
    ss.put(i);
    ss.get();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

При запуске на `Windows` в среде `VS 2017` с родным компилятором потребление памяти только растет (как в отладочной, так и в релизной версиях).

Comment: а shrink_to_fit не должно давать "негативных последствий на производительность"?

Comment: Да, должно, но не в таком виде, как ручной вариант, да еще и без возможности задать емкость.

Comment: если я правильно понимаю документацию - `It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.` - то эта функция может вообще ничего не делать:)

если оно опять будет расширятся, то зачем куда то ужимать? выделите достаточно памяти при старте и работайте. А в конце освобождайте. Это будет самый эффективный способ

Comment: Каким образом при использовании `std::stringstream` я могу заранее указать объем используемой памяти?

Comment: @wololo, на тестах все выглядит именно так, как вы описали.

Comment: показывайте тесты.

Comment: Тест очень простой - в бесконечном цикле в `std::stringstream` записывается N-байт данных и затем считывается N-байт данных. Потребление памяти все время растет, шагами, по +50%.

Comment: @wololo, пример добавил.

Comment: В предыдущем комментарии я написал `потребляемая память в процессе работы не изменялась`. Это не верно. В своём тесте я допустил ошибку.

Comment: у меня получился такой shrink-to-fit `std::stringstream sp;
        sp << ss.rdbuf();
        sp.swap(ss);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По идее такое поведение обусловлено реализацией: `std::stringstream` хранит всю скинутую строку независимо от того, что было из него прочитано. Cудя по API ни какого контроля над этим нет.

Самое простое будет просто создать новый std::stringstream и перекинуть в него всё, что не прочитано.

```
std::stringstream ss;

// ...
ss << "foo bar";
ss >> foo;
// ...

std::stringstream newss{};
newss << ss.rdbuf();
ss = std::move(newss);
```

Можно сделать это немного эффективнее предварительно запросив нужное количество памяти:

```
std::string newBuf;
newBuf.reserve(ss.rdbuf()->in_avail()); // можно аллоцировать и больше
std::stringstream newss{std::move(newBuf)};
newss << ss.rdbuf();
ss = std::move(newss);
// Замечание: ss.str().capacity() будет выводить другое значение размера
// т.к. stringstream::str() возвращает копию строки
```

Не могу утверждать, что это гарантированно предаллокацирует память, но судя по всему это работает.

---

Как вариант, вместо того, чтобы использовать `std::stringstream` можно реализовать свой кольцевой буфер для `std::iostream`, но это уже другая история.

Comment: `у std::stringstream'а на данный момент нет также и способа преаллоцировать память для буфера`. Есть же функция-член [`str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str), принимающая строку, которая будет использоваться в качестве буфера. Причём есть перемещающая версия. Создаём пустую строку. Резервируем необходимое количество памяти. Перемещаем её в `std::stringstream` для использования в качестве буфера. Или не сработает?

Comment: @wololo, я пробовал — не работает... при копировании/перемещении строк нет ни каких гарантий, что зарезервированный размер сохранится... и, по крайней мере, gcc для пустой строки его не сохраняет...

Comment: @wololo, хотя я мог и ошибиться... надо поглубже покопаться до c++20 `str()` должен был возвращать копию... скорей всего я просто её размер смотрел...

Comment: @wololo, да, действительно, был неправ... с `std::stringstream` не работало, потому что `str()` у него возвращает копию, а вариант которые принимает r-value ссылку добавили только в с++20; в `gcc-10` его ещё нет, а в trunk'е [уже есть](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/95cb0fc8c51841cc6a0e51490cb3769eb80fa34c)... поправил ответ... и [вот пример на поиграться](https://godbolt.org/z/MGfoabbh8)...

Answer (score 1):

Чтение данных из потока `std::stringstream` не уменьшает размер внутреннего буфера потока. Оно просто перемещает индикатор позиции чтения вперёд. Перепишем ваш тестовый пример следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss;

    for (char i = '0'; i < '3'; ++i) {
        //ss.str("");

        ss.put(i);
        cout << "tellp: " << static_cast<std::streamoff>( ss.tellp() ) << endl;

        ss.get();
        cout << "tellg: " << static_cast<std::streamoff>( ss.tellg() ) << endl;
        
        cout << ss.str() << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

[Вывод](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4d34b5b12a4d82b):

```
tellp: 1
tellg: 1
0

tellp: 2
tellg: 2
01

tellp: 3
tellg: 3
012
```

По выводу программы видно, что по мере записи и чтения данных в/из потока перемещаются соответствующие индикаторы позиций. Но после чтения из потока размер буфера не уменьшается. Все прочитанные символы остаются во внутреннем буфере.

Для предотвращения неограниченного роста внутреннего буфера необходимо либо перед записью/чтением данных перемещать индикаторы позиций записи/чтения с помощью функций [`seekp()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) и [`seekg()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) в начало буфера. На размер буфера это не повлияет, и старое содержимое не очистит. Просто запись в поток будет перезаписывать уже имеющиеся во внутреннем буфере символы.

Либо полностью заменить внутренний буфер на пустую строку с помощью функции [`str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str).

Если в приведённом примере раскомментировать строку `//ss.str("");`, то [вывод будет таким](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bded5e67d8adcc6e):

```
tellp: 1
tellg: 1
0

tellp: 1
tellg: 1
1

tellp: 1
tellg: 1
2
```